# How to make a phone call button in Android for Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-phone-call

I'm trying to create a calling  button in Android. I created one and it works in all kind of Android device but it's not working on Marshmallow. I don't know why. How to create a calling button for android Marshmallow?

This is the code I used for the calling button :

```
public void button(View v) {

        String number = "12354656";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: hi guys i support all ur answer so let me tell u what was the problem adnroid studio some time he  get confuse between  two import which is (import java.Manifest.*;) and (import android.Manifest;)so if u are using dangerous permission u have to use (import android.Manifest;) and delete  the other one  otherwise it will not work and u will get problems with permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable permission for your app in the phone settings. Look under permissions in settings

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably related to `Runtime Permissions`  introduced in `Android 6.0`.

You can try this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
}
else
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: iam trying it right now its telling me that i cant resolve symbol permission and i already add the permission for CALL_PHONE..  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: as i said `Google` added runtime permission in api 6.0+. You have to specifically ask for runtime permission.

Comment: hi guys i support all ur answer so let me tell u what was the problem adnroid studio some time he  get confuse between  two import which is (import java.Manifest.*;) and (import android.Manifest;)so if u are using dangerous permission u have to use (import android.Manifest;) and delete  the other one  otherwise it will not work and u will get problems with permissions

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this...

put in your android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

get runtime permission for make phone call(Android API version 23 and above)

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL = 111;

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.app_need_call_permission),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.app_need_call_permission),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
            }
        }
```

you will get permission response on

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL) {
            // put your code here to make call
        }
    }
```

then you have to make your phone call

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

for more info https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: bro i did this but its still not recognizing (permission) i even added the permission to the android manifest

Comment: Are you use in Activity or Fragment?

Comment: I have to attach reference link in my answer... it will help you

Comment: ok bro i created a new project in android studio and i did the same steps u told me and it works so what i found that there is some thing i add in my old project that block this permission so do you have any idea about it ? and can i have your email if its possible thank you

Comment: raja@vertace.com

Comment: hi guys i support all ur answer so let me tell u what was the problem adnroid studio some time he  get confuse between  two import which is (import java.Manifest.*;) and (import android.Manifest;)so if u are using dangerous permission u have to use (import android.Manifest;) and delete  the other one  otherwise it will not work and u will get problems with permissions